# Mounting Old HDDs - Not sure filesystem, RAID or not, Linux or Windows

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, filesystem, raid

In a bit of a pickle trying to see what's on some old hard drives sitting around in the basement. I set these up years ago and have no memory of whether they were in a Linux or Windows desktop, QNAP NAS data disks, whether they were part of RAID, ...

I know the basics of mounting disks in Ubuntu, but haven't been able to get either of my disks working after a few hours. Please let me know what additional info is needed, but here's some info to start. I've clipped some of the outputs that aren't relevant (ie, related to my working OS SSD drive). I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS.

```
> sudo parted -l

Model: ATA Hitachi HDS72302 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      20.5kB  543MB   543MB   ext3            primary  msftdata
 2      543MB   1086MB  543MB   linux-swap(v1)  primary  msftdata
 3      1086MB  1991GB  1990GB                  primary  msftdata
 4      1991GB  1992GB  543MB   ext3            primary  msftdata
 5      1992GB  2000GB  8554MB  linux-swap(v1)  primary  msftdata


Model: ATA ST2000DM001-9YN1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      20.5kB  543MB   543MB   ext3            primary  msftdata
 2      543MB   1086MB  543MB   linux-swap(v1)  primary  msftdata
 3      1086MB  1991GB  1990GB                  primary  msftdata
 4      1991GB  1992GB  543MB   ext3            primary  msftdata
 5      1992GB  2000GB  8554MB  linux-swap(v1)  primary  msftdata
```

```
> sudo mdadm --assemble --scan

mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

```
> sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Hitachi HDS72302
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1CFBFA6E-5DE2-4FBB-9434-7F99C33337AE

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1          40    1060289    1060250 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2     1060296    2120579    1060284 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3     2120584 3889240109 3887119526   1.8T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  3889240112 3890300399    1060288 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb5  3890300408 3907007999   16707592     8G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DM001-9YN1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EC428FA6-7CEC-478F-92D2-74905AAD0347

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1          40    1060289    1060250 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc2     1060296    2120579    1060284 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc3     2120584 3889240109 3887119526   1.8T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc4  3889240112 3890300399    1060288 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc5  3890300408 3907007999   16707592     8G Microsoft basic data
```

```
> sudo blkid | grep "sdb\|sdc"

/dev/sdb4: UUID="7969d376-faec-7326-ea1f-a4f0c2b8df31" UUID_SUB="f6237eb6-b37f-c0a8-f26a-f16d7213eec7" LABEL="13" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="96eaad7e-b1f7-4e34-8b4a-2677306ac717"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="e9e3007d-025a-52c7-8ae6-5b33a31d2847" UUID_SUB="735431ba-a8a5-f011-f829-61e1050fbceb" LABEL="256" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="ec845032-7293-48d3-86b8-8c7f9fb058e9"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="ece5dbb9-691e-90c9-a4db-34a830207b1f" UUID_SUB="c9c4ee4b-2070-2c84-a4c8-9487b28a3c54" LABEL="322" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="2badfccd-7cad-419f-9444-10d1b3975888"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="ee9f4571-4934-59be-5dc0-e74b25b989e4" UUID_SUB="a883d2cc-4033-6f60-dd55-7190350fa21d" LABEL="1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="d0d8ce86-e7d8-4424-9160-61d560b53332"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="54f4c84d-2ee5-bf61-c94e-a39e7bc59e02" UUID_SUB="caf1eac9-fead-2a2b-5b28-be7c114f9714" LABEL="9" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="18c315ea-07fc-4bab-85aa-bd9d27062802"
/dev/sdc2: UUID="20248480-66bf-331b-9a09-af592f9fcae9" UUID_SUB="10ff6c2f-43a6-c28a-6987-51ef206255be" LABEL="256" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="40d4646a-2dcd-496a-b0e2-ae174ab21d58"
/dev/sdc5: UUID="9cbe1c40-ad42-6977-2a6c-f80e639e78eb" UUID_SUB="c1fdda6a-9f9f-a199-dc77-965007cdf414" LABEL="322" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="6c7115e9-929a-4707-ad8e-8dd1088b7c0a"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="54f4c84d-2ee5-bf61-c94e-a39e7bc59e02" UUID_SUB="9267de55-e74b-da15-2d45-f76fd89ed2ac" LABEL="9" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="bd4d5447-c888-415d-a9a6-1e1d8c51ce73"
/dev/sdc4: UUID="7969d376-faec-7326-ea1f-a4f0c2b8df31" UUID_SUB="e44c651d-6cc6-6d92-7957-059a2ca3b419" LABEL="13" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="2ddc8849-5e11-4766-a63c-cbd94871b2b4"
/dev/sdc3: PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="fa22f82e-11e3-4bda-ad46-c538a9def5f3"
```

```
> sudo mount /dev/sdc3 /mnt/seagate/

mount: /mnt/seagate: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc3, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

> sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/seagate/

mount: /mnt/seagate: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'.
```

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md126 : inactive sdc2[3](S)
      530124 blocks super 1.0
       
md127 : inactive sdc5[3](S)
      8353780 blocks super 1.0
       
md322 : inactive sdb5[0](S)
      8353780 blocks super 1.0
       
md1 : inactive sdb3[0](S)
      1943559620 blocks super 1.0
       
md256 : inactive sdb2[0](S)
      530124 blocks super 1.0
       
md9 : inactive sdc1[35](S) sdb1[0](S)
      1060216 blocks super 1.0
       
md13 : inactive sdc4[35](S) sdb4[0](S)
      1060256 blocks super 1.0
       
unused devices: <none>
```

```
sudo lsblk -f
NAME                      FSTYPE            FSVER    LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                     squashfs          4.0                                                         0   100% /snap/core20/1587
loop1                     squashfs          4.0                                                         0   100% /snap/core20/1738
loop2                     squashfs          4.0                                                         0   100% /snap/lxd/22923
loop3                     squashfs          4.0                                                         0   100% /snap/lxd/23541
loop4                     squashfs          4.0                                                         0   100% /snap/snapd/17883
sda                                                                                                              
├─sda1                    vfat              FAT32          9105-EA28                                   1G     0% /boot/efi
├─sda2                    ext4              1.0            05bf5b03-73fe-4644-a1f3-9a1adb1d36b4      1.7G     7% /boot
└─sda3                    LVM2_member       LVM2 001       nKZwMd-Bn0n-2J6R-lQsp-n3Pb-TbSg-ix4cmi                
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4              1.0            ac1e13fa-ca2a-4a93-a91e-b74f07475659     46.7G    13% /
sdb                                                                                                              
├─sdb1                    linux_raid_member 1.0      9     54f4c84d-2ee5-bf61-c94e-a39e7bc59e02                  
│ └─md9                                                                                                          
├─sdb2                    linux_raid_member 1.0      256   e9e3007d-025a-52c7-8ae6-5b33a31d2847                  
│ └─md256                                                                                                        
├─sdb3                    linux_raid_member 1.0      1     ee9f4571-4934-59be-5dc0-e74b25b989e4                  
│ └─md125                 LVM2_member       LVM2 001       CYlL8Y-6M52-0BnZ-yuPt-bnOL-zZRv-heV2BA                
├─sdb4                    linux_raid_member 1.0      13    7969d376-faec-7326-ea1f-a4f0c2b8df31                  
│ └─md13                                                                                                         
└─sdb5                    linux_raid_member 1.0      322   ece5dbb9-691e-90c9-a4db-34a830207b1f                  
  └─md322                                                                                                        
sdc                                                                                                              
├─sdc1                    linux_raid_member 1.0      9     54f4c84d-2ee5-bf61-c94e-a39e7bc59e02                  
│ └─md9                                                                                                          
├─sdc2                    linux_raid_member 1.0      256   20248480-66bf-331b-9a09-af592f9fcae9                  
│ └─md126                                                                                                        
├─sdc3                                                                                                           
├─sdc4                    linux_raid_member 1.0      13    7969d376-faec-7326-ea1f-a4f0c2b8df31                  
│ └─md13                                                                                                         
└─sdc5                    linux_raid_member 1.0      322   9cbe1c40-ad42-6977-2a6c-f80e639e78eb                  
  └─md127
```

These disks may have been used in any of the following:

- Windows Desktop (Windows 7 or 10 maybe?)
- Acer Aspire EasyStore (Windows Home Server 2003)
- QNAP NAS
- Ubuntu Desktop (Probably 16.04 or 18.04)

Any tips and guidance is very much appreciated!  I'm somewhat confused by how some commands output input relating to `msftdata` or `Microsoft basic data`, but elsewhere it says the filesystem is `ext3` or mentions `linux_raid_member`.

Comment: I assume its only the 2tb volume you are interested in... from experience, if you have used the motherboards built in raid controller, the chance og recovering without that specific brand and model are slim.l, since the setup of those "raid controllers" is in my experience nonstandard and not interchangeable with other methods of raid setup. You also mentioned qnap. I would look up the model and see what type of raid controller they have, because you may be in the same boat. it is worrisome that the `fdisk -l` command has no detail on the 1.8Tb partition at all. Have you tried `lsblk -f`?

Comment: I've edited the original post to include `fdisk -l` output.

So there's two 2TB HDDs I'm trying to access. I've made some progress with `mdadm --stop /dev/md##` but I think at least `/dev/sdb` / the Hitachi was used in my old QNAP as I'm seeing `WARNING: Unrecognised segment type tier-thin-pool` when running `vgck --updatemetadata vg1`